# C# Delegate Instantiation

Tags: delegates

```
class Program
{
    delegate void StringProcessor(string input);

    class Person
    {
        string name;

        public Person(string name) { this.name = name; }

        public void Say(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} says: {1}", name, message);
        }
    }

    class Background
    {
        public static void Note(string note)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("({0})", note);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person jon = new Person("Jon");
        Person tom = new Person("Tom");

        StringProcessor jonsVoice, tomsVoice, background;

        jonsVoice = new StringProcessor(jon.Say);
        tomsVoice = new StringProcessor(tom.Say);
        background = new StringProcessor(Background.Note);

        StringProcessor p = new StringProcessor(jonsVoice);
        p += tomsVoice;
        p -= jonsVoice;
        p("Hello");

    }
}
```

This program prints

```
Jon says: Hello
Tom says: Hello
```

instead of

```
Tom says: Hello
```

This removal doesn't work: `p -= jonsVoice;`

But why?

Could you please clarify this or get some useful links about delegate instantiation with another delegate. I'm interested in undercover information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A delegate is an object which represents a method and, optionally, the "this" object associated with that method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596516109-03-09.aspx)

When you combine delegates using the += operator, the result is a [Multicast Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173175%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that represents a list of delegates to be invoked.  (In fact all delegates are Multicast delegates, creating a delegate like this:

```
jonsVoice = new StringProcessor(jon.Say);
```

results in a Multicast Delegate with a single delegate in it's InvocationList).

You can remove delegates from the Invocation list by using the -= operator.

So why didn't your example above work?  Because there is no delegate matching jonsVoice in the invocation list of p.

p has an invocation list that consists of two delegates:

- one pointing at the Say method of the tomObject
- one pointing at the Invoke method of a StringProcessor object

That is because you initialised p by passing the StringProcessor constructor another StringProcessor:

```
jonsVoice = new StringProcessor(jon.Say);
...
StringProcessor p = new StringProcessor(jonsVoice);
```

Resulting in a StringProcessor delegate that points at another StringProcessor delegate.

You can examine the invocation list of a delegate by calling the [GetInvocationList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) method on that delegate.  This will return an array of delegates in the order they would be invoked.

```
StringProcessor p = new StringProcessor(jonsVoice);
p += tomsVoice;
p -= jonsVoice;

foreach (var delegateItem in p.GetInvocationList())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Delegate of {0}.{1}", delegateItem.Target.GetType().Name, delegateItem.Method.Name);
}
```

Which results in:

```
Delegate of StringProcessor.Invoke
Delegate of Person.Say
```

When you call p -= jonsVoice, the invocation list does not contain a delegate that points at the Person.Say method of the jon objects (like jonsVoice does) and so there is nothing to remove.

If you initialize p like this instead:
    StringProcessor p = jonsVoice;

You should get the results you expect.